# How to pass Regular Expression value to 'HTTP Request'

Tags: regex, jmeter

In "**Http request default**" i have set url has [jmeterbook.aws.af.cm] and in '**HTTP Request**' i set the path as [/${ind}], 
In "**Regular expression Extractor**" i have given as,

> Reference Number:  ind
>   Regular Expression: index
>   Template: $0$

I just want to pass the Regular Expression value(ind) to the "**HTTP Request**"->path but it's not taking up the value

Comment: your approach is wrong ... please go through some Jmeter tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regular expression:

```
.+jmeterbook\.aws\.af\.cm/(.+)
```

Then set the template to:

```
$1$
```

This will return whatever it finds after *jmeterbook.aws.af.cm/